# How does cmake handle duplicate build options

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

My repo has a bit messy CMAKEList which configures many compile options.
If I enable -Og but the legacy later also defines -O3, which option are chosen effective?
Is it

1. First one appears
2. Last one appears
3. Looser option (or stricter option)

Another example would be enable lto and disable lto (just an example)

Alwasy appreciate the community for sharing valuable knowledge!

Comment: "If I enable -Og but the legacy later also defines -O3, which option are chosen effective?" - CMake just passes options to the **compiler**. It is up to the compiler to interpret them. That is, you should address your question to the compiler which you use (for which CMake configures the project).

Comment: BTW, your title is misleading: `-Og` and `-O3` are NOT "duplicate build options". Duplicate options are e.g. `-Og` and -Og`. Please, make the title be corresponding to the question body, not to be contradicting it.